# How to get text of selected item from the main list in listview android

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

In this when I long press on any of the name in the list context menu pops up and then again it asks to choose one of the option.

What I want is to generate a toast of the name selected in the main listview. Images are attached for better understanding. For Eg when I press on Dr.David Hicks a toast should appear of his name.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNGuq.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1sEX.png)
can  somebody pls help me with this

```
package com.example.tamukcompscfaculty;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] Professors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Professors);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ProgAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Professors);
        setListAdapter(ProgAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        if(v==getListView()){

            MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
            menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.More);
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.details, menu);

        }

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    }


}
```

Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tamukcompscfaculty.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profs"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/FacultyText"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp" >

    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/engineering" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_data.xml is a file in Values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name = "Professors">

        <item >Dr. David Hicks</item>
        <item >Dr. Mohammad S. Khan</item>
        <item >Dr. Young Lee</item>
        <item >Dr. Mais Nijim</item>
        <item >Dr. Ashraf Yaseen</item>
        <item >Ms. Jeong Yang</item>
        <item >Dr. Abdelrahman Elleithy</item>
        <item >Dr. Wei-Da Hao</item>
        <item >Dr. Syed Iqbal Omar</item>
        <item >Dr. Muhammad Aurangzeb</item>
        <item >Dr. Gahangir Hossain</item>


    </string-array>    

</resources>
```

Strings.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">TamukCompScFaculty</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="FacultyText"><u>Faculty Office Hours Details</u></string>
    <string name="Office_Hours">Check Office Hours</string>
    <string name="Email">Email Id</string>
    <string name="Phonenumber">Phone Number</string>
    <string name="More"><u>Click below to check the details</u></string>
    <string name="title_activity_start">StartActivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: "_Images are attached for better understanding_" Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your `Professors` member variable and then override `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` where you can get the position of list item clicked. So your code will be :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private String[] Professors;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Professors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Professors);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ProgAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Professors);
        setListAdapter(ProgAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        if(v==getListView()){

            MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
            menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.More);
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.details, menu);

           //get the position of row clicked
           AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
           int position = info.position;

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Professors[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ajay add this line in the onCreated method: getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); i'll update my answer.

Comment: @Ajay see the updated answer. This should work for you.

Comment: @Ajay if that helped, feel free to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement OnItemClickListener and then override the method onItemClick and don't forget to register the listener in your OnCreated method.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private String[] Professors;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Professors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Professors);
    ArrayAdapter<String> ProgAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Professors);
    setListAdapter(ProgAdapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this)
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if(v==getListView()){

        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
        menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.More);
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.details, menu);

    }

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Professors[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] Professors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Professors);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ProgAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Professors);
        setListAdapter(ProgAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        getListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Professors[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```